# Free Tools for Hard Drive Diagnostics

Tags: hardware, diagnostic

Are there any free tools available to perform hard drive diagnostic?
I have an old 3.5 IDE Samsung HDD which I use as an external drive through USB connection. I recently started to have problems with accessing some of the data.

Answer (score 3):

The [Ultimate Boot CD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/) has some Hard Drive tools on it that should detect any errors on the drive. Just make sure that you back up all your data FIRST. Doing intense testing on a bad drive may lead to worse failure and data lost.

Answer (score 2):

Personnaly, I have used the following in the past:

- HD Tach from Simpli Software (http://www.simplisoftware.com/Public/index.php?request=HdTach)

or

- HD Tune from EFD Software (www.hdtune.com)

Cheers,

Thomas

Comment: I've used HD Tune and it's been great every time.

Comment: http://www.hdtune.com -> Added link for the lazy

Answer (score 2):

I thought [SpinRite](http://www.grc.com/spinrite.htm) was free, but I guess it isn't any more. Based on that I would use the manufacturers diagnostics tool, see samsungs [here](http://www.samsung.com/global/business/hdd/support/utilities/Support_HUTIL.html).

Comment: SpinRite has never been free as far as I can remeber, but it is the best in the business. If you really want the data back then use SpinRite, only a hardware failure (like a spindle breaking) will stop it. Plus if it doesn't work, there is a money back guarantee.

Comment: I just checked their website, they also don't offer a trial. Weird. Maybe I did buy it and I just forgot.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia has a list of [harddisk diagnostic software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_S.M.A.R.T._tools). These programs are called S.M.A.R.T. tools, they detect if some of the reliability parameters are not okay. I used  the free [Active@ Hard Disk Monitor](http://www.ntfs.com/disk-monitor.htm) to run checks on my harddisks.

Answer (score 0):

The answers above with HD Tune and UBCD4Windows are great but I always would go with the manufactures own test tools. That's what I do with my Seagate HDs.

Here's Samsungs utility: [ES Tool](http://www.samsung.com/global/business/hdd/support/utilities/ES_Tool.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you do find out that a HDD is failing, you may want to check out [Recovery Is Possible](http://freshmeat.net/projects/recoveryispossible/).

Answer (score 0):

Along with all the other suggested options, you may want to look at more basic hardware factors:

- try using a different usb cable
- try a different usb port on the computer
- try using the hard drive in a different external drive case
- if available, try using esata
- try connecting the hard drive directly to your motherboard and see if the problem occurs

And as always, if you think the drive is flaky, make a backup of the data on it asap.  It will protect your data from a drive that may be dying and give you the option of doing destructive data tests if need be.

Answer (score -1):

You can grab Hiren's boot cd which contains some free tools for this purpose. [Website is here](http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd)

Maybe you'll have to attach your drive to the IDE bus for doing your maintenance work.

Comment: I don't think that CD is legit. Most of that software isn't free, just pirated. Just a warning. Check out Ultimate Boot CD instead, perhaps?

Comment: Yep, last time I checked it was full of malware too. I say UBCD4Win if you want a bootable CD, it includes the HD Tune software commented above.